# React JS: The certificate key "key.pem" is invalid. Passphrase required for encrypted key

Tags: reactjs, ssl, npm

I am trying to pass a certificate and a key that I created using openssl. They are referenced inside my .env file like this:

```
HTTPS=true
SSL_CRT_FILE=./cert/cert.pem
SSL_KEY_FILE=./cert/key.pem
```

However, when running the command "npm start", it gives out an error saying `The certificate key "key.pem" is invalid. Passphrase required for encrypted key`

How do I pass the passphrase in the .env file?

Comment: Your key file is encrypted while it should not be. You somehow exported the private key incorrectly.

Comment: @WiktorZychla That makes sense. I have used [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-make-react-js-use-https-in-development-4ead560eff10) to create the private key. Do you, by any chance, know what could be done to export the private key correctly?

Comment: [This is how](https://serverfault.com/questions/366372/is-it-possible-to-generate-rsa-key-without-pass-phrase)

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thank you so much, it worked!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved!

As Wiktor Zychla said in the comments above, I exported the private key incorrectly. You can find the correct way in the comments as well.

([link](https://serverfault.com/questions/366372/is-it-possible-to-generate-rsa-key-without-pass-phrase))